# Doubt regarding inverse CDF/quantile function or qpois in R

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, quantiles

Let's say I have a poisson with mean 9.29 (lambda). The probability of random variable being less than equal to 1 and 2 are "0.0009502101" and "0.004935002" respectively (i.e. P[X<=1] = 0.0009502101 & P[X<=2] = 0.004935002) . The value of qpois at these quantiles are 1 and 2, as they should be. However, when I try to compute qpois(0.003, 9.29), I get 2 as output. I am failing to understand why a quantile value < "0.004935002" is still giving 2 and not 1? Will it be mathematically wrong if theoretically the function starts giving 1 as value?

Comment: There's a disconnect here: `qpois` is the *quantile* function.  Its argument is a *cumulative* probability, not an individual probability.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, that's correct! It's the probability  P[X<=1] = 0.0009502101 and P[x<=2] = 0.004935002 .  However I still don't understand why qpois(0.003, 9.29) will give 2 as output not 1. I am editing my question to make the correction.

Comment: The need to examine so many significant digits might be hampering your ability to see what's going on.  Study what happens with $\lambda=1$ instead.

Comment: Ahh! Got it - must be my tiredness. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a 4-place table of PDF and CDF values
for $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 9.29),$

```
x = 0:5
pdf = round(dpois(x, 9.29), 5)
cdf = round(ppois(x, 9.29), 5)
```

(Ignore row numbers in brackets `[ ]`.)

```
cbind(x, pdf, cdf)
     x     pdf     cdf
[1,] 0 0.00009 0.00009
[2,] 1 0.00086 0.00095
[3,] 2 0.00398 0.00494
[4,] 3 0.01234 0.01727
[5,] 4 0.02866 0.04593
[6,] 5 0.05325 0.09918
```

Now here are a few selected quantile values.

```
qpois(.00493, 9.29)
[1] 2

qpois(.00494, 9.29)
[1] 3
qpois(.00495, 9.29)
[1] 3
qpois(.00496, 9.29)
[1] 3
qpois(.01727, 9.29)
[1] 3

qpois(.01728, 9.29)
[1] 4
```

The figure shows that many horizontal lines might meet
the CDF curve at the same x-value.

```
curve(ppois(x, 9.29), 0, 4, n=10000, col="blue", lwd=2)
points(0:4, ppois(0:4, 9.29), pch=19, col="blue")
 abline(h = .01, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(v = 3, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

This kind of difficulty does not arise with many commonly used continuous
distributions, such as $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma=7).$

```
pnorm(46.02, 50, 7)
[1] 0.2848235
qnorm(0.2848, 50, 7)
[1] 46.01952
qnorm(0.2849, 50, 7)
[1] 46.02158

curve(pnorm(x, 50, 7), 30, 80, col="blue", lwd=2)
 abline(h = 0.2848235, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 abline(v = 46.01952, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: +1.  Perfect illustrations.  But note that continuous distributions are not entirely problem-free: a horizontal line may meet the graph along an entire segment.

Comment: Thanks whuber and BruceET for the help! For some reason I spent an hour yesterday trying to figure out what's happening. Then it struck me all of sudden after whuber's comment on question - guess I was too tired from a long day yesterday. But seeing as this is an excellent explanation - I am accepting this as answer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: The quantile function has to be defined very carefully, especially for discrete dist'ns because it has uses beyond what may be obvious. For example, `rnorm(100, 20, .3)` gives 100 observations from BINOM(20, .3). But so does `qbinom(runif(100), 20, .3)`.